# Finding and replacing a hyphen (-) between two integers of variable length

Tags: php, regex, text, preg-replace

I've got a large chunk of text, in that text there is several occurrences of text like this `201014120 - 10`. There is also text with normal hyphens (-).

What I'm trying to do, is to replace the hyphen between the two numbers with a comma `,` but *not* replacing any other hyphens in the text. I'd like to do this with PHP's `preg_replace`.

The numbers are not the same and the length of each numbers will not be the same for all the text.

I've tried different types of regex expressions, both with the code and with this very nice [website](http://preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com).

Comment: Give sample of your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that you match only hyphens surrounded by digits:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\s*-\s*(?=\d)/', ', ', $input);
```

`(?<=\d)` is positive lookbehind: it will only allow the regex to match if it's preceded by a digit. Conversely, `(?=\d)` is positive lookahead. The regular expression will match (and therefore replace) any whitespace surrounding the hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$str='e-mail 201014120 - 10 e - mail 201014120-10';    
echo preg_replace('/(\d+\s*)-(\s*\d+)/','${1},${2}',$str);

>>> e-mail 201014120 , 10 e - mail 201014120,10
```

Match `(\d+\s*)-(\d+\s*)`:

```
\d+ # One or more digits 
\s* # Zero or more white space characters
-   # Literal hypen
()  # Capture group
```

Replace `${1},${2}`

```
${1} # The first captured group
,    # A literal comma
${2} # The second captured group
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
preg_replace("/(\d+)-(\d+)/g","$1,$2",$text);
```

or, if your text is as stated "digits" "whitespace" "hyphen" "whitespace" "digits"

```
preg_replace("/(\d+\w*)-(\w*\d+)/g","$1,$2",$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '201014120 - 10';
$pattern = '/(\d+) - (\d+)/';
$replacement = '$1,$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```